# Button function not repeating

Tags: javascript, loops, events

Hey guys am new to javascript development and i was trying to do something with the events which is really simple..I have made a button in which when a button is clicked an image hides  out and when the button is clicked again the images comes..But when i do the same process again it didnt work.When i refresh the page it works..The code is

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<img src='gun.jpg' id="babe"></img>
<input type="button" id="a" value="babe" onclick="addelement(this);" >
</form>
<script>

  function addelement(event) {

    document.getElementById('a').onclick = function (s) {

    document.getElementById('babe').style.display = "inline";

  }

  document.getElementById('babe').style.display = "none";

}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

When I tried this code it works but when I click the button the third time the image doesn't disappear. What I need is to make thee process repeat. How can i do this? Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: The reason you're code worked only once is, that for with the first click, your `onclick` method was not existing, so the image got hidden. On each following click, this method got executed setting display to inline.

Answer (score 4):

In your HTML you are setting when button is clicked call `addelement` function so `.onclick=` stuff is not required inside `addelement`, also you just have to verify current display value to toogle between `hide` and `inline`

```
function addelement(event) {
  var img = document.getElementById('babe');
  var isHidden = img.style.display == "none";
  img.style.display = isHidden ? "inline" : "none";
}
```

**EDIT:**

Code trying to compute initial display style (if browser supports)

```
function addelement(event) {
  var img = document.getElementById('babe');
  var style = img.style;
  if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    style = window.getComputedStyle(img);
  }
  var isHidden = style.display == "none";
  img.style.display = isHidden ? "inline" : "none";
}
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't work as expected if the image is originally hidden by CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/zoohcveh/8/

Answer (score 1):

i have created jsfiddle for you...

I have updated your code and removed unwanted events and code:-

code:-

```
  <script>
    var img = document.getElementById('babe');
    img.style.display = "none";

    function addelement(event) {
        img.style.display = img.style.display == "none" ? "inline" : "none";
    }
  </script>
```

new example:-http://jsfiddle.net/zoohcveh/10/

Comment: Why are you re-adding the same onclick handler every time it's clicked?